# Call .NET function in external DLL from postgres

Tags: .net, postgresql, dll

It's possible to call C functions through [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) but how can .NET functions in dll's be called from postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an external function using [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createfunction.html). This reference implies that the DLL must be a native DLL using the C calling convention and hence cannot handle managed code.

You could try to use [Mono AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) or [MS Native Image Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80,loband).aspx) to compile the managed code to native code, but I cannot tell if this will result in a native DLL using C calling convention. You have to try.

If this does not work, you could create an unmanged wrapper for your DLL.

**UPDATE**

You have to write a wrapper - [C-Language Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/xfunc-c.html) states that the DLL must include a magic block that will not be availiable if you compile managed code to native code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some overhead to calling C functions from PosgtreSQL, [External Functions](http://linuxgazette.net/139/peterson.html) in Postgres @ Linux Gazette covers writing such a method in C. I would surmise from that that you could, if you REALLY need to, build a hosting module that loads a CLR instance and provides an entry point into your C# method that is mapped with the appropriate Postgres linking logic. This seems extremely costly.

Another approach that might be better would be to encapsulate the C# method (which I am assuming is already written) in a web service, and use a wrapper (not necessarily C, but one of the lighter-weight extension development bindings for Postgres) that will call out to the web service.