# Postgres dllimport like SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, user-defined-functions

Is there any similar thing like SQL Server's UDF (where a function can be exported in a DLL and imported as a function in SQL Server) in Postgres?

For example the function I want to import has the following signature:

```
public static extern double* svd(double[] a, int d);
```

the Dll import looks like  this:

```
[DllImport("D:\\my.dll", EntryPoint = "mydll")]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call .NET function in external DLL from postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841158/call-net-function-in-external-dll-from-postgres)

Comment: Are you trying to write a UDF in C# and use it in T-SQL code?
If so, look at CLR Integration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That's not a dupe. Please read the question.

Comment: This is not at all what the questioner wants. He wants to import a DLL into Postgres.

Comment: Yes what happens here is that i have a c code that is in a dll and in c# I am calling the extern functions, and finally I use the c# udf as an stored procedure, but I do not know what would be the approach in Postgres...

Comment: @codekaizen The first answer shows how to call native functions and a workaround for managed function calls. We're not breaking new ground here.

Comment: @todda.speot.is - I disagree. Note this question has a method signature. It is more specific than the other question, and my answer also address this specific need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Create Function` in Postgres:

```
CREATE FUNCTION svd(double*, int) RETURNS double*
AS 'c:/path/mydll.dll'
LANGUAGE 'C';
```

More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html

You'll likely need to use composite types since it appears you're manipulating matricies with variable numbers of rows and columns.

Comment: Yes I am manipulating matrices, about the composite types can you give a little more detail?

Comment: @cMinor You can represent an n-dimensional matrix using an n-dimensional PostgreSQL array, so you won't have to implement your own data types. Just write a C function that accepts a double[][] array and returns another double[][] then map it into SQL using "CREATE FUNCTION". Read the PostgreSQL sources for examples - look up functions that take and/or return n-dimensional arrays and look at their C implementations. The documentation covers the basics of C functions well.